# Is it possible to create a Queue on Database rows?

Tags: android, architecture, multiprocessing, interprocess

Right now I am trying to create a process, where I want to insert data in table and some observers will get notified and able to edit the data upon their interest. Below is a rough idea on how to do it. Can anyone please suggest the model/arch how I can achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried with Room + LiveData?

Answer (score 5):

Follow [this tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-training-livedata-viewmodel/#0) on Room, ViewModel, and LiveData.

Room is a SQL database abstraction which can expose its data through LiveData. ViewModel is a class that holds data for the UI and survives configuration changes. LiveData is an observable container for data that is aware of the android lifecycle so you don't have to manage it in the lifecycle callbacks.

Basically, you create a Room database then expose LiveData objects to the ViewModel. The ViewModel in turn exposes LiveData objects to the fragment/activity. The fragment or activity observes the ViewModel's LiveData by attaching an Observer. The Observer defines how the fragment/activity reacts to changes in the data.

If you prefer RXJava you can follow [this tutorial](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/room-rxjava-acb0cd4f3757) instead. It's essentially the same, but instead of exposing data with LiveData you use reactive streams.

Edit: here's a really good article on architecture: https://proandroiddev.com/android-architecture-starring-kotlin-coroutines-jetpack-mvvm-room-paging-retrofit-and-dagger-7749b2bae5f7